# How do I wrap text on UILabel that is created in a storyboard?

Tags: swift

I am having difficulty wrapping the text in UILabel and it is going out of bounds. I've tried to set the numberoflines to 0 in the utility pane after clicking on UILabel in Storyboard, but it still doesn't wrap. Just to clarify, I created the UI Label in Storyboard and connected to ViewController with IBOutlet.

[image: Issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge you need to add proper constraints to UILable, Just add leading, trilling and top constraints.